# Mudar conteúdo da modal com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom dia,

Sei muito pouco de JQuery e JavaScript (Quase nada) e estou com um problema.
É o seguinte:

No meu site tenho dois botões, que abrem uma modal (gerada com css). O conteúdo da modal é basicamente o mesmo, contendo um formulário de contato.

Mas preciso que o título e o valor do meu input hidden seja modificado, de acordo com o botão que cliquei.

Resumindo: Preciso que quando clique no botão do primeiro link, o título receba Plano 1, e o valor do input hidden receba FORM_PLANO1.

E quando clique no botão do segundo link o título receba Plano 2 e o valor do input hidden receba FORM_PLANO2.

Meus links que abrem a Modal:

```
<a href="atendimento-online#send" class="btn2">Plano 1</a>

<a href="atendimento-online#send" class="btn2">Plano 2</a>
```

O HTML da Modal:

```
<div id="send" class="modalDialog">
<div>
 <div class="header_modal">
    <span class="icone_modal"></span>
    <div>
      <span class="title_modal">Atendimento Online | (TITULO Plano1/Plano2) </span>
      <span>Preencha os dados para solicitar um contato</span>
    </div>
</div>
 <a class="close" title="Fechar" href="ferramenta-de-disparo-de-email-marketing#close">X</a>
<div>
<form name="contact" action="contact/send" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_input" value="(FORM_PLANO1/FORM_PLANO2)" />
<div class="input-group01">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nome</span><input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" />
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Email</span><input type="text" name="email" class="input_email" />
</div>
```

O CSS que gera a Modal:

```
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}


.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
width: 630px;
position: relative;
margin: 5% auto;
background: #fff;

-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
}

 .close {
background: #318A14;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

input, textarea { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; 
border: 1px solid #C9C9C9; 

color: #545658; 
padding: 8px; 
font-size: 14px; 
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('.btn2').on('click', function(e){
    var plano = $(this).data('form');
    var titulo = this.innerHTML;

    $('#send .title_modal').html('Atendimento Online | ' + titulo);
    $('#send input[name="form_input"]').val(plano);
});
```

Ele escuta cliques nos botões e busca titulo e plano. Juntei no HTML desses botões `data-form="FORM_PLANO1"` e `2` para o jQuery ir buscar.

Na segunda parte aplica esses valores.

Comment: Sergio, primeiramente muito obrigado pela resposta. Mas como disse não sei quase nada de JS, e estou tendo dificuldade para implementar isto no meu código, podes me ajudar?

Comment: @GWER dá uma olhada a este jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1z2w9s57/ e coloca na tua pergunta o código que abre o modal assim posso recriar no jsFiddle e dar-te um exemplo a funcionar.

Comment: Adicionei o css que gera a modal a pergunta, a parte do título funciona, mas tenho um problema. Coloquei os botões como `Plano 1`e `Plano 2` para exemplificar melhor, mas no meu html original, os dois recebem `Saiba mais`. Ou seja, o título dos dois está recebendo `Saiba mais`. O resto consegui resolver.

Comment: Consegui resolver a questão, MUITO OBRIGADO pela ajuda!

Comment: @GWER eu estive fora e agora que cheguei ao computador vi que já tinhas conseguido. Boa!